# Show image if author meta (profile fields) exists outside loop

Tags: custom-field, loop, images, user-meta, profiles

I am trying to show the profile fields (like AIM, Jibber) outside the loop. I managed to do that with

```
<?php
global $post;
$author_id=$post->post_author;
?>

<?php
$field='aim';
the_author_meta( $field, $author_id );
?>
```

But now, I can't put an image beside it if such a field exists. This works inside the loop, but not outside:

```
<?php if (get_the_author_meta('aim')) {
echo "

<div class=schrijver-socialmedia>
  <img src=http://blablabla.com/images/aim_icon.png /> 

"; } ?>
```

How do I get this image outside the loop and only if the field exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_the_author_meta` accepts two parameters

- `$field` - Field name for the data item to be returned.
- `$userID` - If a user ID is passed to the function, it will return data for the specified user ID.

So just pass the user ID or author ID eg:

```
 if (get_the_author_meta('aim',$author_id)) { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_the_author_meta` is a wrapper around `get_user_meta`, which is what you should use instead.

```
$value = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single );
```

$single is a true or false value, if you want a single meta field, pass true. If you have multiple fields of the same name, pass false, and it will return an array instead.

Since you only have a single field, named aim, pass in true

e.g.

```
$aim = get_user_meta( $author_id, 'aim', true );
```

Here $author_id is the user ID of the author/user you're querying.

To check if the user has an aim, check the $aim value. get_user_meta will return false if no meta of that key was found.

```
if ( $aim != false ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

But what if there is an aim field and that field is empty? Then we can make use of `empty()` to check both cases, resulting in:

```
$aim = get_user_meta( $author_id, 'aim', true );
if ( !empty( $aim ) ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Then of course you could always pass in the author ID as the second parameter to `get_the_author_meta`

- [More details on `get_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)
- [More details on `get_the_author_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta)
- Other useful functions:

  - [the_author_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta)